# Integer solutions question simple

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose I have:
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 12$$

and I want to find all solutions $x_i \geq 1$

Well firstly I can give 1 to each x, so that leaves me with:
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 8$$
Then, I can just make 3 dividers, like such:
$$x_1 | x_2 | x_3 | x_4$$
and so my answer is $$\binom{8+3}{3} = \binom{11}{3}$$
My sheet says:

$\textit{Theorem}$: The number of ways to distribute $r$ identical objects into $n$ distinct boxes with at least $one$ object in each box is:
$$\binom{r-1}{n-1}$$
As you can see, this formula works, cause $\binom{12-1}{4-1} = \binom{11}{3}$

But I'm not sure where they got this formula, and why it works?

Comment: yes sorry, got my subtraction wrong. thanks for edit!

Comment: The ways of partitioning, say, the number 6 into three positive summands can be counted as follows.  First, write $6$ as
$$
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1.
$$
Now choose and circle two of the pluses.  That will give three summands.  E.g., 
$$
1 \oplus1 + 1 + 1 \oplus 1 + 1 = 1 + 3 + 2.
$$
Therefore, the number of partitioning $6$ into $3$ summands is "5 choose 2".

See the answer to Exercise 2.11 in this book: https://books.google.com/books?id=PS8lQQ8AOHYC&pg=PA3&dq=discrete+mathematics+sadovsky&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHtYXPoN7QAhVY12MKHXSSAH4Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=partition&f=false

Comment: what do you mean by "That will give three summands"

Comment: Summands means addends.  Three quantities that add up to 6.  (In the example I gave, the summands are 1, 3, and 2.)

Comment: where did u get 1 3 2 from tho?

Comment: Have you read my first comment above?  1, 3, 2 are just an example of a partition of 6 into 3 summands (see the equation with the circled pluses).  The example is intended to show that each partition is obtained by circling 2 of the 5 pluses.  Therefore, the total number of such partitions is the number of ways to choose 2 objects out of 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify non-negative integers, the dividers can be before the first ball, after the last ball, or have multiple dividers between balls, as shown below.

$\bullet \bullet\bullet \bullet |\bullet\bullet|\bullet \bullet\bullet\bullet  \bullet\bullet |\quad$ [ $0$ in $x_4$ ]

$| \bullet \bullet\bullet\bullet | \bullet\bullet\bullet \bullet\bullet |\bullet \bullet\bullet\quad$ [ $0$ in $x_1$ ]

$\bullet \bullet\bullet\bullet | | \bullet\bullet\bullet |\bullet\bullet\bullet \bullet\bullet\quad$ [ $0$ in $x_2$ ]

On the other hand, when you specify positive integers, the dividers must be within the boundaries of the balls, and with at most one divider between two balls, e.g.

$\bullet | \bullet\bullet\bullet |  \bullet\bullet\bullet |\bullet\bullet\bullet \bullet\bullet\quad$

Thus there are just $(n-1)$ spaces in which to place the $(k-1)$ dividers singly.

Answer (score 1):

That formula can be viewed as the *glueing* of your 2-step thinking.

You had $r $ objects for $n $ boxes with no empty box. You then subtracted $n $ from $r $, saying you now want to distribute $r-n$ balls over $n $ boxes without caring about having empty boxes. Using the *"dividers"* train of thought you see there are

$${(r-n) + (n-1)\choose{n-1}} $$ ways of doing it. But that is just the same as

$${r-1\choose{n-1}} $$

which is the theorem's formula.

Comment: So we basically integrated the subtracting step into the equation?

Comment: @KracX pretty much yeah. That is one way of putting it. Check avs's comment though, he provides a very nice and intuitive explanation